# How should we count the number of distinct pairs / tuples in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose the schema is like this:

```
First Name | Last Name | Age | ID
====================================
John         Smith       18    123
John         Smith       21    234
John         Smith       19    123
Cathy        Zhang       20    144
Cathy        Zhang       20    144
Jackie       Chan        35    456
```

Suppose I want to count the number of distinct pairs after each (first name, last name). So that the output should be:

```
John         Smith       3
Cathy        Zhang       1
Jackie       Chan        1
```

I think I can first do:

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,Age,ID,COUNT(*);
```

And then

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,COUNT(*)
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: `Cathy Zhang` pair result should be 2 right?

Comment: @techdo: Actually it should be 1. Since Cathy Zhang has the same Age and ID for the two entries we are having.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To return the count of each distinct firstname lastname, you would use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

In your above example, I think you meant Zhang to have a count of 2 though.

--EDIT

If I'm understanding your latest comment correctly, you want to also use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age, Id, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, Age, Id FROM TableName) T
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Age, Id
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had thought. These two are subsequent steps. After the second step, the result should be John Smith 3, Cathy Zhang 1, Jackie Chan 1, is that right?

Comment: And you can leave age and id off -- not sure what you need :-)

Comment: Excuse me, what's the use of that `T`?

Comment: When using sub queries, you need to use an alias in most (if not all) RDBMS.

Comment: Looks like you can leave off the alias in Oracle -- needed in MySQL and MSSQL -- you can see the broken fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea52/1

Comment: +1 On the edit. The query to get what the OP wanted for output would be `SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, Age FROM TableName) T GROUP BY FirstName, LastName`

Answer (score 2):

Try using,

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, count(1) FROM name_tab GROUP BY firstName, lastName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT * FROM YourTable 
    ) X
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Comment: I don't think so. When I tried in MS SQL 2005, query `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM YourTable` returned 5 distinct rows (in sample there are 6 rows). Please try to execute the same script in your sample table if you have...